# Boundedness of general relativity Hamiltonian

Tags: general-relativity, energy, hamiltonian-formalism

When one consider a lagrangian and construct hamiltonian, we expect to be bounded below. While looking to the Hamiltonian formulation of general relativity, I have difficulties to see how it can be bounded (I mean the hamiltonian off-shell otherwise it's zero).

1. How this can be shown?
2. Is it related to the positive energy theorem?